# Message queue load test with JMeter 2.11 and JMS Weblogic 10

Tags: jmeter, message-queue, load-testing, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to build a load test for my queues, which are Weblogic Queues, but I can't figure out which weblogic libraries I need for this. At least, that's what I think my problem is (because I get ClassNotFoundExceptions). I've already copied

```
weblogic.jar
wlclient.jar
wljmsclient.jar
```

into my jMeter/lib directory.

but I still get ClassNotFoundError like:

```
Response message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/utils/collections/ConcurrentHashMap
```

Here, also the full stacktrace...

```
    2014/09/16 19:17:19 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: weblogic/utils/collections/ConcurrentHashMap java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
    weblogic/utils/collections/ConcurrentHashMap
        at weblogic.jndi.spi.EnvironmentManager.<clinit>(EnvironmentManager.java:19)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:307)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:277)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.getInitialContext(JMSSampler.java:424)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.threadStarted(JMSSampler.java:319)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:597)
        at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:961)
        at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:946)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:566)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:554)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.utils.collections.ConcurrentHashMap
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 17 more

    2014/09/16 19:17:19 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: Session may not be null while creating message java.lang.IllegalStateExcepti
    on: Session may not be null while creating message
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.createMessage(JMSSampler.java:179)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.sample(JMSSampler.java:140)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

... and, also my JMeter Configuration:

[image: Configuration]

After the first run I get the following error: ConcurrentHashMap not found

[image: ConcurrentHashMap not found]

And on every run after the first one: EnvironmentManager can't be initialized

[image: EnvironmentManager can't be initialized]

What am I not doing right here? Thanks a lot for the help!

Regards,
al

Answer (score 0):

According to http://mazanatti.info/index.php?/archives/68-JMeter-configure-and-post-JMS-messages-to-Weblogic-Server.html you probably need wlthint3client.jar instead of weblogic.jar and wlclient.jar
Combo of wljmsclient.jar and wlthint3client.jar works for me.